# Markup Validation Service problems

Tags: html, markup, validation, strict

i have some problems in order to validate my webpage. here I list them if you can please help me.

---

element X undefined

You have used the element named above in your document, but the document type you are using does not define an element of that name. This error is often caused by:

```
incorrect use of the "Strict" document type with a document that uses frames (e.g. you must use the "Frameset" document type to get the "<frameset>" element),
by using vendor proprietary extensions such as "<spacer>" or "<marquee>" (this is usually fixed by using CSS to achieve the desired effect instead).
by using upper-case tags in XHTML (in XHTML attributes and elements must be all lower-case).

Line 68, column 16: element "figure" undefined

        <figure***>***
```

---

document type does not allow element X here; missing one of Y start-tag

✉

The mentioned element is not allowed to appear in the context in which you've placed it; the other mentioned elements are the only ones that are both allowed there and can contain the element mentioned. This might mean that you need a containing element, or possibly that you've forgotten to close a previous element.

One possible cause for this message is that you have attempted to put a block-level element (such as "

" or "") inside an inline element (such as "", "", or "").

```
Line 44, column 36: document type does not allow element "h4" here; missing one of "object", "ins", "del", "map", "button" start-tag

            <p><h4 class="titlepub"***>***&nbsp;<a href="http................
```

thnx in advance,
Mr.Roll

Comment: Whic version of HTML are you validating against? I don't think that `figure` was standard until HTML5.

Comment: yes , i removes figure and this was solved. the version is DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict

Answer (score 0):

So yeah, just to expand on my comment to the question, the problem with Dandy Roll's code is that he is validating his markup against the XHTML 1.0 Strict DTD. In particular, he made use of the `<figure>` tag (which did not come into standard existence until HTML 5), so his document would not validate.